# How to preserve axioms from the positive numbers in the negative numbers?

Tags: algebra, negative-numbers

It isn't so hard to convince students of grade 8. 9 that $-2$ is greater than $-4$, but it still make some confusion with an axiom says that ( The whole is greater than part ), which is true in the positive numbers. For example if we consider the ( Whole) to be $4$ and the half to be ( The part ), then 4 is greater than its half which is 2. The question is how to convince students that the converse should happen in the negative numbers, i.e, the half of $-4$ ( $-2$) is greater than the ( Whole ) which is $-4$ ?!

Comment: I think I have some idea of what you are asking; to use similar language to yours: When you remove *all* of a number, then you are left with $0$. When you remove *some* (but not all) of a number, then you are left with something closer to $0$. With this conception: Going from a positive number to a new number *closer to zero* means a decrease; going from a negative number to a new number *closer to zero* means an increase. (I would probably model this on the number line.)

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have no problem in explaining that $-2$ is greater than $-4$. The problem is how to convince students that the converse is happen in negative numbers ?

Comment: If your textbook has axiom "the whole is greater than the part", then it had better not be a textbook on real numbers.  Perhaps it is a textbook on geometry or something.

Comment: I think the concept is still strong. Even one stone in the wall is smaller than the wall.

Comment: I believe your statement there is the key: -2 is indeed smaller than -4 -- it's smaller in MAGNITUDE. The magnitude of the part is smaller than the magnitude of the whole.

Comment: Still there is no getting away from the fact that still it is true that -4 is less than -2. That's why we try to use the specific words "less than" and "greater than" rather than "smaller than" and "bigger than", because they are ambiguous when referring to negative numbers. You really do have less if you have -4, because you have had an extra two TAKEN AWAY, so you definitely have less. Another phrase that works is "lower than" and "higher than", because then you can refer to temperature where -4 is indeed lower than -2.

Comment: Following up on @DavidButlerUofA's comment about using different words:  One option is to refer to the symbols "<" and ">" as "comes before" and "comes after", and resist the natural urge to use "less/greater" or "smaller/larger".  That is, they are symbols denoting *order*, not *size*. It is a fact that for positive numbers, small numbers come before large ones; but for negative numbers, "large" (in magnitude) numbers come before "small" (in magnitude) ones.

Comment: I like it @mweiss, but we do need to remember that the official names for those symbols are "less than" and "greater than", so we do need to tell students what people mean when they say those things!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment by @GeraldEdgar and others, I'd like to answer that "The whole is greater than the part" is just not a valid axiom about numbers (of any sort). This statement is relevant for collections (e.g. finite sets, or everyday physical objects), but it doesn't quite make sense regarding numbers.

To provide a concrete example, a statement that 2 is a half of 4 has in its essence a very different meaning than saying that the set {Eve, Sarah} constitutes a half of {Adam, Eve, Abraham, Sarah}. Speaking about parts of numbers appears to me to be an abuse of notation that inevitably leads to confusion.

Perhaps you could provide us with a context for the statement of this "axiom"?

Answer (score 1):

Reflecting on this, I think the difficulty comes because there are 2 ways of interpreting integers which have different ordering functions.

The first (and standard) interpretation is as a totally ordered set, from $^-\infty$ to $\infty$. From this perspective $^-4 < {^-2}$.

The second way (as used in high school physics) is to interpret integers as a 1 dimensional vector. The direction is given by $^+/_-$, and the magnitude is given by a totally ordered set from $0$ to $ \infty$. From this perspective, it would make sense to think of $^-4 > {^-2}$, as a velocity of $^-4$ is clearly bigger than a velocity of $^-2$.

However, to be mathematically consistent, interpretation 2 integers are only partially ordered, with no overall supremum, as $^+4$ and $^-4$ are not able to be compared. It may be best not to call directed natural numbers such as these integers, and refer to them as 1D vectors. However, they do conform to your whole/part intuition, and are routinely used according to this intuition, while still (incorrectly?) being called integers.

Comment: This is an interesting direction (pun intended) that I haven't considered. How then would you respond to the OP's question? Does the statement "The whole is greater than the part" make sense as a learning aid given this viewpoint?

Comment: @yoniLavi Integers are learned by middle school, while 1D vectors are used in high school, so I can't imagine the vector interpretation actually being useful for real life teaching of integers. They would just confuse the standard definition.